# Are $AC^{0}$ algorithms interesting to research communities?

Tags: algorithms

I have seen many research papers with log space algorithms, but not many with $AC^0$ algorithms. Is there any reason for this.

**Question :** Are $AC^{0}$ algorithms interesting to research communities?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathsf{AC^0}$ algorithms are quite weak. For example, $\mathsf{AC^0}$ cannot compute parity or majority. However, it can compute approximate majority, as shown by Ajtai; see [Viola, On Approximate Majority and Probabilistic Time](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/papers/BPvsE.pdf), for a better construction and for references to Ajtai's work.

$\mathsf{TC^0}$ is a slightly stronger class, also consisting of polynomial size circuits having constant depth, but allowing threshold gates. Such circuits can compute division, as shown by [Hesse, Division is in Uniform $\mathsf{TC^0}$](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-48224-5_9.pdf), improving on works of others (starting with Beame, Cook and Hoover). The related problem of iterated integer multiplication is also in $\mathsf{TC^0}$.

Comment: Perhaps the take-home here is that $\mathrm{AC}^0$ algorithms _are_ interesting; it's just that there aren't many of them. (Yes, yes, technically there are infinitely many but...)